# In Solidity, how does the slot assignation work for storage variables when there's inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, storage, solidity

In a simple solidity contract, without inheritance, storage variables get assigned sequentially starting from slot 0.

But in case of inheritance, the inherited variables appear before or afterwards?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The assignment is as follows: first to the inherited variables, from the leftmost contract to the rightmost, finishing with the current contract you're in.

In the following example `C` inherits from `Base` and `Base2`, in that order. The slot assignment will start from `Base`, following `Base2`, and finally `C`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5;

contract Base {
    uint256 basevar = 0;
    constructor() public {
        basevar = 1;
    }
}

contract Base2 {
    uint256 basevar2 = 2;
    constructor() public {
        basevar2 = 1;
    }
}

contract C is Base, Base2 {
    uint256 cvar = 0;

    function getCvar() public view returns(uint256) {
        return cvar;
    }

    function getBasevar () public view returns(uint256) {
        return basevar;
    }

}
```

`basevar` gets assigned slot 0,
`basevar2` gets assigned slot 1,
and `cvar` gets assigned slot 2.

Comment: Can you link reference?

Comment: @benoit the docs say "For contracts that use inheritance, the ordering of state variables is determined by the C3-linearized order of contracts starting with the most base-ward contract" https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.14/internals/layout_in_storage.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage

Answer (score 3):

I had done some extensive testing so I wanted to add another answer to clarify things.

**Simple Example:**

```
contract A is B, C, D {}
```

The Storage will be arranged like this:

```
Storage B;
Storage C;
Storage D;
Storage A;
```

Now, if you want to Add `E` to your already written contract (And not cause memory collisions), this is how you go about doing it.

**NOTE**: `A2` should be an empty contract, so it takes no slots. (Just in case), and thus can be ignored as it will have no storage.

```
Contract A2 is A, E { }
```

The storage will be arranged like this:

```
Storage B;
Storage C;
Storage D;
Storage A;
Storage E;
```

This will make it safe to upgrade.

If you do it the opposite way:

```
Contract A2 is E, A { }
```

`E` will be set on the top, and you will mess up the order of your storage slots.

```
Storage E;
Storage B;
Storage C;
Storage D;
Storage A;
```